# Trying to resolve 'no matching mac found error', any ideas

Tags: bash, ssh

Trying to grab some logfiles for troubleshooting and can't seem to ssh into the server, any ideas where to start looking?

```
ssh -v maint@192.168.133.25
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.133.25 [19.34.133.25] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /u/fred/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /u/fred/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 server hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
```

Comment: Your ssh client is a _bit_ old.

Comment: Did you try `man ssh` and search for MAC?